# Setting textView.typingAttributes foreground color in Swift 4

Tags: ios, uitextview, nsattributedstring, swift4, xcode9-beta

I'm using the below method to set my textView.typingAttributes foreground color to red in Swift 3.

```
textView.typingAttributes[NSForegroundColorAttributeName] = UIColor.red
```

Now, that I've migrated to Swift 4 its showing error, I tried like below but its still showing error. Whats the correct way to set it?

```
textView.typingAttributes[NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor] = UIColor.red
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
textView.typingAttributes[NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor.rawValue] =
    UIColor.red
```

Answer (score 1):

For Swift 4.2 and Swift 5.0, it is

```
textView.typingAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:UIColor.red]
```